# SEO on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, seo

I've come across a question about letting Google grab data based on pages via AJAX.  So what I mean is, Usually people will have a `Contact` `About` `Product`, etc...  Pages that are already created.  Now what if I have a page that will pull other pages via AJAX, how can I let Google know that these pages exist?

I have a custom navigation utilizing WordPress.  I have set pages created for each nav option.  When that nav is selected it simply pulls on that content through AJAX so there is no reload.  My question is how can I get that SEO effect on that without having to go to a new page

Please let me know if there is any confusion on my question?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide hashbang `#` urls to allow SE to crawl your contents, read more in https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started